# How do you correctly define a command in Java?

Tags: java, subclass

I am learning to program using becker robots. What I am struggling with is how to shorten an argument. For example, change:
turnLeft()
turnLeft()

into something like:
turnAround()
 I've tried doing this with several different commands
        import becker.robots.*;

```
public class addingservices extends Robot
{

  public addingservices(london, 5, 5, Direction.SOUTH)
  { super(london, 5, 5, Direction.SOUTH);
    }

City = London = new City();
Robot lisa = new Robot(london, 1, 1);


public void turnAround()
{ this.turnLeft();
  this.turnLeft();
}

public void move3()
{this.move();
  this.move();
  this.move();
}

public void turnRight()
{this.turnLeft();
  this.turnLeft();
  this.turnLeft();
}

public void turnRight()
{this.turnAround();
  this.turnLeft();
}

lisa.turnAround();
lisa.move3();
lisa.turnRight();
lisa.move3();

}
```

I'm very new to Java so please have mercy on my soul

Comment: So what happens with the code you've given; what's the problem(s)?

Comment: when i call them at the bottom the code doesn't run. All of the errors read 'identifier required' and I do not know what to make of it

Comment: Since you are extending robot, you should not need "this." everywhere,  You can just call "turnLeft()" (etc).  OTOH, these should not be harming anything.  What happens when you run it?

Comment: *Gives mercy to your soul*

Comment: @Choirbean I get 'identifier required' errors. I've somehow got a feeling that my first few lines of code are the issue here.

Comment: @HugoSousa my soul just leveled up. Thanks

Comment: Isn't there a stack trace you can post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a main method to actually run something.  Something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    addingservices lisa = new addingservices([some arguments go here])
    lisa.turnAround();
    lisa.move3();
    lisa.turnRight();
    lisa.move3();
}
```

This is typically placed at the bottom of your class, inside of the class code braces.  IOW, it would replace the four commands you have for "lisa" right now.
Additionally, you have a strange constructor heading:

`public addingservices(london, 5, 5, Direction.SOUTH)`

I am surprised that Java is allowing this to compile.  You need something with defined arguments, such as (borrowed from the Robot constructor):

`public addingservices(City aCity, int aStreet, int anAvenue, Direction aDirection)`

Then, in the constructor itself, you would pass on aCity, aStreet, anAvenue, and aDirection to the super constructor.

In main, then, you would need to create a City:

`City london = new City(10,10);`

Which would allow you to pass in london as an argument in main.  So, the line that read [some arguments go here] would now read:

`addingservices lisa = new addingservices(london, 5, 5, Direction.SOUTH);

Is that clear?

If my answer helps you, I would be much obliged if you accepted it (clicked on the check box on the left).  This way, I will be rewarded for my efforts.

Comment: if possible, could you please show me how to arrange my top few lines?

Comment: Your top lines aren't the problem.  What error are you getting right now?

Comment: For line 6 which is 'public addingservices(london, 5, 5, Direction.SOUTH)' I  am getting  these errors:
<identifier> expected
 illegal start of type

Comment: Yes.  Did you read the rest of my response?  Start from "Additionally, you have a strange constructor heading:" - it talks about how to fix that.